# Do we usually have $\sum^{\infty}_j Y_j \in L_p$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let's imagine I have $Y_j \in L_p$, for all $j$.

Do I also have that $\sum^{\infty}_j Y_j \in L_p$?

I know that the partial sums belong to $L_p$ since that space is also a vector space.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a non-zero constant function in $L_p[0,1]$.

Comment: @TomekKania Many thanks!

Comment: ... or something like $Y_j = 1_{[j-1,j]}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so that this question is not left 'answered'. This is the answer given in the comment by Tomek Kania.

Let $Y_j=k$, with $k \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. Then $(\int |Y_j|^p dx)^{1/p} = (\int_{[0,1]} |k|^p \ dx)^{1/p}= (k^p)^{1/p} < \infty$, so $Y_j \in L_p$

However, $\sum_j Y_j=\infty$.